# Flask app with two processes running in parallel (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, flask, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to build a flask app with multiprocessing such that I run two different processes and have communication between them.

first process `p1` should load a person detection model, read camera (webcam), detect persons and create a batch of 30 frames and send this batch to second process `p2` through `multiprocess.Pipe()`. This batch is received using `Pipe()` in second process `p2` where another deep learning model is loaded to detect hat and inference and post processing is done on this batch. Now the program works in series (extremely slow), first p1, then p2, then p1 and so on.

I have built the below code which is sequential, but I want both processes to be working in parallel.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import sys
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
import json
import shutil
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CaptureCamera():
    def __init__(self, source, batch_size, hat_detection):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dim = dim
        self.source = source

        try:
            # load first person detection model
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading model: {e}")

        if self.hat_detection:
            try:
                # load hat detection model
                print("hat detection model loaded successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading hat detection model: {e}")

    def capture_frames(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source)
        self.video_height = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        self.video_width = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

        while not self.stop:
            batch = np.zeros((self.frame_depth, self.dim, self.dim, 3), dtype = np.float32)
            frames_count = 0
            while frames_count < batch.shape[0]:
                success, frame = self.camera.read()
                if not success:
                    break

                # first inference code here

                batch[frames_count,:,:,:] = preprocessed_frame
                if frames_count+1 == self.frame_depth:
                    self.post_processing(batch)

                frames_count+=1

                if self.show_frame:
                    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', display_frame.astype(np.uint8))
                    frame_data = jpeg.tobytes()
                    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame_data + b'\r\n')
                if not success:
                    break

    def stream(self):
        return Response(self.capture_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

    def post_processing(self, Xsub):
        # second model inference
        # post processing code here
```